# How to stop css conflict

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-5

I am developing ruby on rails project and needed to add photo editing feature. So I bought photo editing project consists of index.html and assets(js,css,images,fonts).

Both are working well in several projects and making problem in merging.

Here index.html is including `assets/js/script.min.js` and `assets/css/script.min.css`.

I couldn't understand `.min` file because of large capacity and not well formated.

So I added `assets` of photo editing to `vendor\assets\photo-edit`.

And copied 'index.html' to `photo-edit/index.html.erb`. Now everything is working well except `css`.

I saw `assets` of photo editing and founded these things. It is containing `bootstrap` folder in `css`.

I think if I prevent `default bootstrap` from ruby on rails project in `photo-edit/index.html.erb` this will work properly.

Hope simplest, completed answer from Ror engineers.

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve css conflicts by requiring the assets in the correct order. If you have two CSS rules on the same class, there is always going to be conflict, but you can control which version takes precedence by requiring THAT version last.

so in this case you should require `photo-edit` css after you require `bootstrap`

```
//=require bootstrap
//=require photo-edit
```

Then your `photo-edit` CSS will override all of the conflicting rules with bootstrap CSS.